# Working in Pandas with variable names with a common suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I do most of my data work in SAS but need to use python for a particular project (I'm not very competent in python).  I have a dataframe like this:

```
    values = ['a_us', 'b_us', 'c_us', 'a_ww','b_ww','c_ww']
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1, 6), columns=values[:6])
```

One thing I need to do is calculate the ratio of US to WW for each of companies a, b and c. I know how to do it the long way in python-- I'd just do this for each company:

```
    df['*company*_ratio'] = df['*company*_us']/df['*company*_ww']
```

But, how would can I do this without having to write out each equation?  I am thinking I could do something like

```
    for x in [a,b,c]:
```

or I could define a function.  However, I don't know enough to implement either of those options or even what to search to find an answer (as I'm sure it's been asked before).  In SAS I would just write a macro that fills in *company*.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure somebody will present a nicer/more clever way so I'll just leave the loop as a comment: `for x in ["a", "b", "c"]: df[x+ '_ratio'] = df[x + '_us']/df[x +'_ww']` (note that a, b, and c are not variables so you'll need `"`)

Comment: in addition to my answer - if you have only one row you should probably restructure the data so a,b,c are rows and ww, us are columns - than the computation is much simpler

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `values[:6]`? You'll get the exact same result just using `values`.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies-- they are very useful.  @MattDMo, you are right: the [:6] is not necessary. I didn't realize that though until you pointed it out-- thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first find [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values by first char of columns by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
print df.columns.str[0].unique()
['a' 'b' 'c']
```

Or by first substring if columns are [`splited`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `_` (better for real data).

```
print df.columns.str.split('_').str[0].unique()
['a' 'b' 'c']

for x in df.columns.str[0].unique():
    df[x + '_ratio'] = df[x + '_us']/df[x + '_ww']
```

**Comparing**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
values = ['a_us', 'b_us', 'c_us', 'a_ww','b_ww','c_ww']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1, 6), columns=values[:6])

df['a_ratio'] = df['a_us']/df['a_ww']
df['b_ratio'] = df['b_us']/df['b_ww']
df['c_ratio'] = df['c_us']/df['c_ww']
print df
       a_us      b_us      c_us      a_ww      b_ww      c_ww   a_ratio  \
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894  1.007213   

    b_ratio   c_ratio  
0  1.688142  0.933223
```

is same as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
values = ['a_us', 'b_us', 'c_us', 'a_ww','b_ww','c_ww']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1, 6), columns=values[:6])

for x in df.columns.str[0].unique():
    df[x + '_ratio'] = df[x+'_us']/df[x+'_ww']
print df
       a_us      b_us      c_us      a_ww      b_ww      c_ww   a_ratio  \
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894  1.007213   

    b_ratio   c_ratio  
0  1.688142  0.933223
```

Comment: I would use `for x in set(c.split('_')[0] for c in df.columns.tolist())` instead, because real company names will most probably have more than one character

Comment: Yes, you are right, so I add second solution based by `split`. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2):

You should use MultiIndex 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

you should read the section, but your specific case can be:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 6), columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([['us', 'ww'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]))

ratio = df['us']/ df['ww']
```

the result is a data frame with 3 columns a,b,c the 3 requested ratios